# Can I slice a word with </span> for the sake of structured data?

Tags: html, search-engine, schema.org, microdata, structured-data

I have this line inside a `ProfessionalService` itemscope:

```
Az <span itemprop="makesOffer">ágyi poloska irtását</span> permetezéses módszerrel végezzük.
```

This is in Hungarian and the problem comes from my language too. For search engines I would like to communicate the offer is "ágyi poloska irtás" without the addendum "át" so it would look like this:

```
Az <span itemprop="makesOffer">ágyi poloska irtás</span>át permetezéses módszerrel végezzük.
```

Is this legal? Can I break a word with a `</span>` closing tag?

*Sorry I can't come up with an English example. The example sentence is about how the company exterminate bed bugs it would read like this in English: `The <span itemprop="makesOffer">bed bug extermination</span> done by spraying method.` but in English it works.*

Comment: I see no reason why this isn't valid - html validators don't complain about it and in [html5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element): The span element doesn't mean anything on its own, but can be useful when used together with the global attributes

Comment: So it doesn't break the word on a higher level when search engine indexes it?

Comment: @Pete that is not helpful. I saw those answers but you see I use it for structured data. For simple text I would use span for CSS reasons, but here I try to tell google not use the whole word as data. I do not know if it is a good thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is valid and it can make sense to do this.

Any conforming Microdata parser will get the value "ágyi poloska irtás" for the property `makesOffer`.

Following the HTML5 specification, consumers would have no reason to break the word (e.g., by adding whitespace or a line break) if it contains a `span` element (… which does *not* necessarily mean that you won’t find consumers that do this nonetheless).